# Search for a list in a list and insert it into the map

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My class is a

```
class Movie 
{
private String title;
private int year; 
private List<String> actorsSurnames;
}
```

I want to create a query in the repository:

```
Map<String,List<String>> findByActorsSurnames(List<String> actorsList);
```

I would like to get pairs of a movies and actors that play in them.
Example of the outcome:

```
"Titanic": [0]:"Winslet",[1]:"DiCaprio"
"Avatar":[0]:"Worthington"
```

Is that even possible only in query without any java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.return.types), supported return type don't have Map except for [Vavr](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.collections-and-iterables.vavr) library.

So my best guess for your example would be to get query return type as `List<Movie>` & then  do transformation:

```
List<Movie> findByActorsSurnames(List<String> actorsList);
```

Then in your java code:

```
  ..
  for(Movie m: repository.findByActorsSurnames(list)){
  map.put(m.getTitle,m.getActorsSurnames);
  ..
  }
  ..
```